# Why does $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ instead of homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, functions, definition

I want to learn why does $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ **isomoprhic** to $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ not **homomorphic**.  For example let's define a map $$\phi:\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2}$$ by $\phi([0])=0$ and $\phi([1])=1$ where [.] is an equivalence class. In text books $\phi$ is said to be a **isomorphism**.

However I cannot see how $\phi$ is an **injective** mapping. Because it maps entire class to one element. Doesn't it mean that it maps every element in a class to one element. So how is it injective? Or do we count a class as one element. In that case I can't see why we do it like that.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z = \{ [0],~[1]\}$. So the elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ are the class $[0]$ and $[1]$. The class counts as one object.

Comment: I don't think "homomorphic" means anything in group theory. There are always homorphisms between any two given groups. Some times there is only the trivial homomorphism, but there is always at least one.

Comment: In quotient sets of the set $X$, elements are equivalence classes in $X$, i.e. an entire equivalence class is regarded as a single element in the quotient. Why we do that? Because it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Because it maps entire class to one element." In $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, an entire class *is* one element. So a function that sends each class to its own element is injective, and if it is also surjective and a homomorphism, then it is an isomorphism.

The map $\phi: \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_2$ does come from a map $\phi':\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_2$ which is definitely not injective, since $\phi'(0) = \phi'(2)$, but $0\neq 2$. However, for $\phi$, we have $[0] = [2]$, so $\phi([0]) = \phi([2])$ is not a hinder for injectivity.

Answer (score 0):

It is injective because:

- there are only two classes: $[0]$ and $[1]$;
- each class is mapped to a different element.